# How can I model data for a datable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a datatable where I am using a framework.
For now I am only mocking data because I don't have straight directions from my boss yet.

In the datatable docs say this:

> `rows`:
>   The `rows` prop is where you provide us with a list of all the rows that you want to render in the table. The only hard requirement is that this is an array of objects, and that each object has a unique `id` field available on it.
>
> `headers`:
>   The `headers` prop represents the order in which the headers should appear in the table. We expect an array of objects to be passed in, where `key` is the name of the key in a row object, and `header` is the name of the header.

The headers are going to be hardcoded:

For that I have this:

```
const tableHeaders = [
    {
      key: 'device',
      header: t('cancellations.device'),
    },
    {
      key: 'ticketNumber',
      header: t('cancellations.ticketNumber'),
    },
    {
      key: 'itemsCancelled',
      header: t('cancellations.itemsCancelled'),
    },
    {
      key: 'requestDate',
      header: t('cancellations.requestDate'),
    },
    {
      key: 'status',
      header: t('cancellations.status'),
    },
    {
      key: 'requestedBy',
      header: t('cancellations.requestedBy'),
    },
  ];
```

And before I had this hardcoded which is what I need to model and keep it exactly as it is, not hardcoded but with real data:

```
const rows = [
    {
      id: 'a',
      device: t('Device 1'),
      ticketNumber: t('Ticket Number'),
      itemsCancelled: t('Items Cancelled'),
      requestDate: t('Request Date'),
      status: t('Status'),
      requestedBy: t('Requested By'),
    },
    {
      id: 'b',
      device: t('Device 2'),
      ticketNumber: t('Ticket Number'),
      itemsCancelled: t('Items Cancelled'),
      requestDate: t('Request Date'),
      status: t('Status'),
      requestedBy: t('Requested By'),
    },
    {
      id: 'c',
      device: t('Device 3'),
      ticketNumber: t('Ticket Number'),
      itemsCancelled: t('Items Cancelled'),
      requestDate: t('Request Date'),
      status: t('Status'),
      requestedBy: t('Requested By'),
    }
  ];
```

And the real data comes like this:

```
"CancellationRequests": [
    {
      "accountId": 232279,
      "billingCancelReasonId": null,
      "createDate": "2018-09-18T11:28:47-07:00",
      "id": 17195077,
      "modifyDate": "2018-09-18T11:28:48-07:00",
      "notes": null,
      "statusId": 2,
      "ticketId": 65626859,
      "account": null,
      "items": null,
      "status": null,
      "ticket": null,
      "user": null,
      "itemCount": null,
      "__typename": "SoftLayer_Billing_Item_Cancellation_Request"
    },
    {
      "accountId": 232279,
      "billingCancelReasonId": null,
      "createDate": "2018-09-10T11:11:05-07:00",
      "id": 17183859,
      "modifyDate": "2018-09-10T11:11:06-07:00",
      "notes": null,
      "statusId": 2,
      "ticketId": 65169379,
      "account": null,
      "items": null,
      "status": null,
      "ticket": null,
      "user": null,
      "itemCount": null,
      "__typename": "SoftLayer_Billing_Item_Cancellation_Request"
    }
]
```

So, comparing the real data with the hardcoded rows, it should match like this:

```
      id: row.id,
      device: row.account,
      ticketNumber: row..ticketId,
      itemsCancelled: row.itemCount,
      requestDate: row.createDate
      status: row.status,
      requestedBy: row.user,
```

I am getting the values like this:

data.SoftLayerCancellationRequests.map(item => item);

But I don't know how to assign them to the proper `key: value` in a new object.

PS: I am using Reactjs.

Library use for components: http://react.carbondesignsystem.com/?selectedKind=DataTable&selectedStory=with%20expansion&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=REACT_STORYBOOK%2Freadme%2Fpanel

Comment: It looks like the framework is not specified in your post, it might be helpful to include that info in your post. Currently you have a lot of data, but no real info what you have tried already

Comment: Hi @Icepickle I added a reference to the component I am using to the post: http://react.carbondesignsystem.com/?selectedKind=DataTable&selectedStory=with%20expansion&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=REACT_STORYBOOK%2Freadme%2Fpanel

Comment: true, but the page you link to has a great amount of sample code, which matches almost one to one with the data you provided here, so once again, where would your problem be?

Comment: @Icepickle I don't know how to assign them to the proper `key: value` in a new object. So I can send the proper prop already modeled.

Comment: As far as I can see, the datatable does that work for you, you simply provide it with rows and headers, and it will map cells with an id and a value property.  And the data as you have it, is already perfect for how the datatable expects it

Comment: You already have the matchups shown in the last section you labeled "it should match like this" so use those inside Array#map() to create the array you need

Comment: @Icepickle There says that `key` on `tableHeaders` should match the keys of the object on `rows`. It is doing it now but with the hardcoded data. Not with the one coming from the backend.

Comment: I need like a kind of an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already done all the hard work. It's just a matter of creating a new mapped array using your key matching already shown in your question

```
const rows = APIArray.map(row => {
  return {
    id: row.id,
    device: row.account,
    ticketNumber: row.ticketId,
    itemsCancelled: row.itemCount,
    requestDate: row.createDate
    status: row.status,
    requestedBy: row.user
  }
})
```